# Error trying to cast to generic type: redundant cast

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm having a generic function that returns a new instance of a subclass of `AnyListVM` implemented basically like this:

```
    public TListVM MakeListVM<TListVM>()
        where TListVM : AnyListVM
    {
        TListVM listVM;
        switch(typeof(TListVM).ToString())
        {
            case nameof(EventListVM):
                listVM = new EventListVM();
                // some more init stuff
                break;

            // some more similar cases

            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        return listVM;
    }
```

The two involved classes look currently like that, without any meaningful implementation yet:

```
public abstract class AnyListVM
{
}

public class EventListVM : AnyListVM
{
}
```

Now Visual Studio underlines my `new EventListVM()` and nags that it can't implicitly convert `EventListVM` to `TListVM`.

Okay, so I thought I simply add an explicit cast:

```
        listVM = (TListVM)new EventListVM();
```

But nope. Now Visual Studio underlines it again and says that it's a redundant cast. The offered automatic fix would be to remove the cast again. Infinite loop.

What is going wrong here, why am I not allowed to do this cast, explicitly or implicitly?

Comment: Strangely, if I write `listVM = (TListVM)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TListVM));` instead of `listVM = new EventListVM();`, it does not comply. Why that?

Comment: The statement `listVM = (TListVM)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TListVM));` has no references to concrete types, so the compiler never has to try casting to or from `EventListVM` in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one glaring thing in your implementation that is incorrect, which other's have pointed out but haven't addressed satisfactorily.  If you intend to **instantiate** `TListVM`, then you need to change two very important parts.  First the new code listing:

```
public TListVM MakeListVM<TListVM>()
    where TListVM : AnyListVM, new()
{
    TListVM listVM = new TListVM();

    EventListVM evtList = listVM as EventListVM;
    if (evtList != null)
    {
        // set evtList properties.  You can't change
        // the instantiation method.
    }

    // repeat for other constructs.

    return listVM;
}
```

Now, to expound a bit.  The generic where clause needs to specify that you intend to create the `TListVM` with a parameterless constructor.  To do that, you need to specify `new()` as a generic constraint.

This greatly simplifies your implementation which only knows there is something called `TListVM` that has a base class of `AnyListVM` and has a constructor with no parameters.  There's no need for a complicated switch statement, or using the `Activator`.

Any time you are dealing with generics, work with your generic parameter directly.

---

Based on further information, the switch statement is still the wrong tool.  Generics necessarily constrain how you work with your object.  You can't change the constructor, but you can specialize how you set properties after the object is instantiated.

Above I changed the listing to show how to set those properties directly.

If, instead you were dead set on having different constructors, etc. then you would have to approach it differently.  You would have to return the base class and **not** `TListVM`.

```
public AnyListVM MakeListVM<TListVM>()
    where TListVM : AnyListVM
{
    return MakeListVM(typeof(TListVM)) as TListVM;
}

private AnyListVM MakeListVM(Type listVM)
{
    AnyListVM listVM;
    switch(listVM.ToString())
    {
        case nameof(EventListVM):
            listVM = new EventListVM();
            // some more init stuff
            break;

        // some more similar cases

        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    return listVM;
}
```

The generic helper method lets you wrap your more generic factory method so it has the signature you want, without causing compile errors.

Comment: Thanks, but there is some data to pass as initialization which is specific to the type, so I need the switch anyway.

Comment: If you implement a switch, then you need to make the different configurations set as properties.  You can't do it as a constructor.  If that's the case, generics are the wrong tool.

Comment: @ByteCommander, added two alternatives to get what you want, addressing the limitations of generics and working around them.

Comment: Thanks, your upper code snippet looks really interesting. I would not have thought of that pattern.

Comment: I didn't know you could call new on a generic type with that constraint specified!  Nice.  +1!

Answer (score 1):

You can't guarantee that `EventListVM` will convert to `TListVM` as according to your generic restriction, one is allowed to pass ANY inherited class of `AnyListVM`, which may or may not be `EventListVM`.  Example, if the caller of this method did this:

```
AnyListVM vm = MakeListVM<SomeOtherListVMConcrete>();
```

It would fail, but shouldn't.

I believe what you really want is to cast your `EventListVM` to `AnyListVM`, the actual base type rather than the generic.

```
AnyListVM listVM = new EventListVM();
```

Still, if you are *always* returning an instance of `EventListVM`, I'd consider removing the generic clause all together and updating the signature to have a return type of `EventListVM`.

Comment: Right, but actually I decide what type I chose to create an instance of based on the generic parameter, so the created object will always match the generic type `TListVM`. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: So is your actual code for `MakeListVM` different than what's in the post?

Comment: I just edited it. The lines I wrote are the same, but there are a few more around them.

Comment: I see.  Thanks, that is clearer.  The answer is still valid, however.  The first line should declare the `listVM` variable as type `AnyListVM` and your compiler errors will go away.  We can see that `TListVM` is always the correct type of what you're assigning because of the switch statement, but the compiler cannot deduce that as it's a runtime resolution.

Comment: But then I get an error in the return line, saying I can't implicitly convert AnyListVM to TListVM. Do I have to add an explicit conversion there then?

Comment: Yes.  You will.  In fact, after looking at your own comment, in my opinon, that's probably the cleanest way to do what you're trying to do...using Activator.

Answer (score 1):

To make your problem more obvious, consider a base class and two children:

```
public class Base { }           //AnyListVM
public class Child1 : Base{ }   //EventListVM
public class Child2 : Base{ }   //OtherListVM
```

now your method looks like:

```
public T Get<T>() where T : Base
{
    //code
    T item = new Child1();
    //more code
}
```

Imagine I send in `Child2`, which is perfectly valid from the method signature.  The method's code now looks like:

```
Child2 item = new Child1();
```

which of course is going to be invalid at compile time.